# Explorer OM is not supported in a 64bit process

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk

I was trying to create send ports using C# .NET through following code :

```
using Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM;


      private void CreateSendPort()


      {
         // connect to the local BizTalk Management database
         BtsCatalogExplorer catalog = new BtsCatalogExplorer();
         catalog.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Initial Catalog=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

         try
         {
            // create a new static one-way SendPort
            SendPort myStaticOnewaySendPort = catalog.AddNewSendPort(false, false);
            myStaticOnewaySendPort.Name = "myStaticOnewaySendPort1";
            myStaticOnewaySendPort.PrimaryTransport.TransportType = catalog.ProtocolTypes[0];
            myStaticOnewaySendPort.PrimaryTransport.Address = "http://sample1";
            myStaticOnewaySendPort.SendPipeline = catalog.Pipelines["Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit"];

            // create a new dynamic two-way sendPort
            SendPort myDynamicTwowaySendPort = catalog.AddNewSendPort(true, true);
            myDynamicTwowaySendPort.Name = "myDynamicTwowaySendPort1";
            myDynamicTwowaySendPort.SendPipeline = catalog.Pipelines["Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit"];
            myDynamicTwowaySendPort.ReceivePipeline = catalog.Pipelines["Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive"];

            // persist changes to BizTalk Management database
            catalog.SaveChanges();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            catalog.DiscardChanges();
            throw e;
         }
      }
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom.sendport%28v=bts.20%29.aspx)

But I'm getting following issue
**Explorer OM is not supported in a 64bit process.**
when this line is executed :

```
BtsCatalogExplorer catalog = new BtsCatalogExplorer();
```

I'm well aware of the [fact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) i.e. : "*Warning
Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll is only supported if used from 32 bit processes. If you are building a solution for a 64 bit system you should not use this library.*"

But in this case how can I create send ports on 64bit machine, Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force it to run in a 32 bit process.

http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/

[image]

Comment: i was going to suggest this. If they only API comes from 32-bit DLLs, then you're going to have to be a 32-bit process. In the same way that Adobe only has flash as a 32-bit dll, and my host browser must be 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

As of BizTalk 2010, this restriction was lifted and ExplorerOM can be used in 64-bit and 32-bit processes.